# Prove if cursors location is within NSButton’s frame

Tags: swift, mouseevent, frame, nsevent, nspoint

I have a custom `NSButton` class and want to check (within `viewWillDraw`) if the users current mouse location is inside the buttons frame.

I get the mouse position using `NSEvent.mouseLocation()`, but that gives me an **absolute** `NSPoint` in relation to the screen itself.

`self.frame` (= NSButton.frame) instead returns some **relative** coordinates, refering to the buttons superview.

As a result, `self.frame.contains(NSEvent.mouseLocation())` does not work and I have no idea how to solve that!

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You can try to convert the mouse position to the button frame.. In ios uiview has method to convert points from one view to others and vis versa.

Comment: @Dasem Thanks for your reply! Couldn’t figure out how. `NSButton` isn’t a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add NSTrackingArea with NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited to your Button

Or you can use this code

Convert NSPoint to superview's coordinate system

`let point = self.superview!.convert(self.window!.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream, from: nil)`

And then just use self.frame.contains

`if self.frame.contains(point)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In my case, I especially need to check this within `viewWillDraw` because I the mouse may not entered and I want to change the buttons behaviour depending on that.

Comment: does it helps now ?